# How do I auto-populate field B after field A is filled from a select options drop down in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, forms, field

I am mapping data to a field A (Products Field) dropdown select options in a React form. I want to auto-populate field B (The price Field) with the amount of product selected in field A.
I am able to list the product option for field A.
How do I populate field B after one option is selected in field A

Below is my React Code

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       
              products: [],

     }
    }

 handleItemNameChange(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value); 
   console.log(this.state.products); 

    const selectedProduct = this.state.products.find(product => 
                             product.id === event.target.value);
    this.setState({item_name: event.target.value, item_price: 
                    selectedProduct.price });
  }

  handleItemPriceChange(event) {
    this.setState( { ...this.state, item_price: event.target.value });
  }


{/**** Field 1     ******/}
   <Field  className="form-control form-control-sm" name="item_name"  component="select"  type="select" 
                                               onChange={this.handleItemNameChange}>
           
                 {products.map((product) => 
                                               <option key={product.id} value={product.id}>   
                                                      {  product.name}
                                               </option>
                                              )}
   </Field>


{/**** Field 2    ******/}

<Field className="form-control form-control-sm" name="item_price" type="text" onChange={this.handleItemPriceChange} />


{/**** end    ******/}
```

[Find Console log results images here. "16" is the Selected Product and the rest are all the listed products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXwvg.jpg)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEfpc.jpg)

Comment: pass a value to field 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set item_price state with the price when setting the item:

```
handleItemNameChange(event) {
  const selectedProduct = this.state.products.find(product => product.id == event.target.value);
  this.setState({item_name: event.target.value, item_price: selectedProduct.price });
}
```

And pass the item_price state as value to Field 2

```
<Field 
    className="form-control form-control-sm" 
    value={this.state.item_price} 
    name="item_price" type="text" 
    onChange={this.handleItemPriceChange} 
 />
```

(And as a side note you don't have to destruct and pass `this.state` to `setState` that will be done automatically for you)

Comment: Thank you for your response.   So I have used your way but I get an error. 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: products is not defined"
so I used called the products array within the Item name handler.  

 let products= this.state.products

  

I am still  getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: selectedProduct is not defined"
and  this error too "Cannot read property 'price' of undefined"

Comment: handleItemNameChange(event) {
    let products= this.state.products

     let  selectedProduct = products.find(product => product.id === event.target.value);
  this.setState({item_name: event.target.value, item_price: selectedProduct.price });
        
    }

Comment: I have updated the code. Did you get it working? if not you show the updated code and error you are facing.

Comment: I have updated the code as you suggested. I am now getting this error "app.js:35405 Uncaught TypeError:  Cannot read property 'price' of undefined"

Comment: can you put
console.log(event.target.value);
console.log(this.state.products);
at the start of handleItemNameChange function and share whats logging in the browser console.

Comment: I have captured  console log results and added the screenshots to the question above

Comment: okay I see, I think the problem is the different data types, so for now just change the === with == in the find method in handleItemNameChange, I have updated the code as well please try it.